# Processing RSS/RDF via xml.dom.minidom

Tags: python, rss

I'm trying to process a delicious rss feed via python.  Here's a sample:

```
...
  <item rdf:about="http://weblist.me/">
    <title>WebList - The Place To Find The Best List On The Web</title>
    <dc:date>2009-12-24T17:46:14Z</dc:date>
    <link>http://weblist.me/</link>
    ...
  </item>
  <item rdf:about="http://thumboo.com/">
    <title>Thumboo! Free Website Thumbnails and PHP Script to Generate Web Screenshots</title>
    <dc:date>2006-10-24T18:11:32Z</dc:date>
    <link>http://thumboo.com/</link>
...
```

The relevant code is:

```
def getText(nodelist):
    rc = ""
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc = rc + node.data
    return rc

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(file)
items = dom.getElementsByTagName("item")
for i in items:
    title = i.getElementsByTagName("title")
    print getText(title)
```

I would think this would print out each title, but instead I get basically get blank output.  I'm sure I'm doing something stupid wrong, but no idea what?

Comment: Have you tried http://feedparser.org/ ?

Comment: This is a simple RSS feed, it has nothing to do with RDF. There are some attributes in your XML which are imported from the RDF namespace, but the feed still remains an RSS feed. Please correct the title of your question to reflect this.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of `ELEMENT_NODE` so every check to `TEXT_NODE` fails. I did not test but I am pretty sure of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the `title` nodes to `getText`, whose `nodeType`s are not `node.TEXT_NODE`. You have to loop over all the children of the node instead in your `getText` method:

```
def getTextSingle(node):
    parts = [child.data for child in node.childNodes if child.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE]
    return u"".join(parts)

def getText(nodelist):
    return u"".join(getTextSingle(node) for node in nodelist)
```

Even better, call `node.normalize()` before calling `getTextSingle` which ensures that consecutive children of type `node.TEXT_NODE` are merged into a single `node.TEXT_NODE`.

Comment: First, this works -- thanks!

I'm learning Python and attempting to wrap my head around:

[child.data for child in node.childNodes if child.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE]

I believe it's similar to:

for child in node.childNodes: 
  if child.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE

But don't understand where child.data is coming into play.  (I imagine it's in the docs, but couldn't find the relevant info on docs.python.org)

Comment: This construct is called a *list comprehension*. You can read more about it here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions